# Ошибка при сборке dll в visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2017

Использую Visual Studio 2017. Есть проект по созданию внешней компоненты для 1с. На выходе должна быть готовая dll компонента. Пытаюсь сделать build. Но все время появляется ошибка

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Rabbit, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Writing file 'C:\Users\503053244\git\rabbit\MANIFEST.h'.
1>XSD : error : There was an error processing 'include\MANIFEST.xsd'.
1>
1>If you would like more help, please type "xsd /?".
1>  - Error generating code for DataSet ''.
1>  - Unable to convert input xml file content to a DataSet. The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:enumeration' element is not supported in this context.
1>  - The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:enumeration' element is not supported in this context.
1>Done building project "Rabbit.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Файл MANIFEST выглядит так -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://v8.1c.ru/8.2/addin/bundle" targetNamespace="http://v8.1c.ru/8.2/addin/bundle" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:complexType name="Bundle">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Bundle description</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="component" type="Component" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Name component</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Component">
        <xs:attribute name="os" type="OSType" use="required">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Platform type</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string" use="required">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>File name</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="ComponentType" use="required">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Component type</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="object" type="xs:string" >
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Object name</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="arch" type="ArchType" use="required">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Architecture</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="client" type="ClientType" >
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Client type</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="clientVersion" type="xs:string" >
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Client version</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="buildType" type="buildTypeEnum" >
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Build type</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="codeType" type="codeTypeEnum" >
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Code type</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="OSType">
        <xs:enumeration value="Windows"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Linux"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="MacOS"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="iOS"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Android"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="WindowsRuntimePhone"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="WindowsRuntime"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="ComponentType">
        <xs:enumeration value="native"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="com"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="plugin"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="ArchType">
        <xs:enumeration value="i386"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="x86_64"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="ARM"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Universal"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="ClientType">
        <xs:enumeration value="1C:Enterprise"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Firefox"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="MSIE"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Safari"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Chrome"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="buildTypeEnum">
        <xs:enumeration value="developer"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="release"/>
    </xs:simpleType>    
    <xs:simpleType name="codeTypeEnum">
        <xs:enumeration value="c++"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="java"/>
    </xs:simpleType>        
</xs:schema>
```

С чем она может быть связана?

Comment: В самой первой строке у Вас указано: В промежуточном каталоге (Debug \) содержатся файлы, к которым предоставлен общий доступ из другого проекта (Rabbit 2.vcxproj). Это может привести к неправильной очистке и восстановлению поведения.

Comment: Я удалил все данные о втором проекте, строка с предупреждением исчезла, а вот ошибка осталась

Comment: В этом случае обновите вопрос.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: xs:enumeration не поддерживается в текущем контексте. Если "Unable to convert input xml file content to a DataSet", то попробуйте взять этот самый "input xml" и проверьте его на соответствие XSD-схеме (благо онлайн сервисов для этого много).

Comment: А что это за xml файл? Файла с таким названием в проекте нет. P.S. я с visual studio и тем более с c++ никогда не работал, это моя первая задача, собрать dll.

Comment: В XmlSchema (файл xsd) перечисление (enumeration) _не может_ быть вложено напрямую в узел `simpleType`. Дополнительно должно быть ограничение (restriction) с базовым типом. См, например, [здесь](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_facets.asp). Где вы взяли этот файл MANIFEST.xsd? Он некорректный.